# Populate spinner from database

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to fetch data from database and display in spinner.
 but it is not work properly and crash my application.
  So i kindly request to u , if u have good solution then send to me plz.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> arr_adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  sp.setAdapter(arr_adp);  arr_adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  try
  {
  db.open();  
   Cursor cur=db.GetStudent();
   int cur_item=cur.getCount();
   if(cur.moveToFirst())
   {
             do
             {
                 arr_adp.add(cur.getString(0));
                
            }   while(cur.moveToNext());
         }    
  db.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Exception handle"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this  [Sample for Spinner](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-spinner-example/)

For Database example see this [Notepad Application](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

download the Zip file and check it..

Comment: Thanks for sending me to good link but that display data in spinner from array. Actually i want to display from database using cursor adapter.

Comment: So, First Store data into array from the database and then set array to that spinner .